# Add Map within a Map in a column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the `Metadata` column i have a `Map` type value:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|       Noun| Pronoun|  Adjective|Metadata                        |
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|      Homer| Simpson|Engineer   |["Age": "50", "Country": "USA"] | 
|      Elon | Musk   |King       |["Age": "45", "Country": "RSA"] |
|      Bart | Lee    |Cricketer  |["Age": "35", "Country": "AUS"] |
|      Lisa | Jobs   |Daughter   |["Age": "35", "Country": "IND"] |
|      Joe  | Root   |Player     |["Age": "31", "Country": "ENG"] |
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to append another `Map` type value in the `Metadata` against a key called `tags`.

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Noun| Pronoun|  Adjective|Metadata                                                            |
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Homer| Simpson|Engineer   |["Age": "50", "Country": "USA", "tags": ["Gen": "M", "Fit": "Yes"]] | 
|      Elon | Musk   |King       |["Age": "45", "Country": "RSA", "tags": ["Gen": "M", "Fit": "Yes"]] |
|      Bart | Lee    |Cricketer  |["Age": "35", "Country": "AUS", "tags": ["Gen": "M", "Fit": "No"]]  |
|      Lisa | Jobs   |Daughter   |["Age": "35", "Country": "IND", "tags": ["Gen": "F", "Fit": "Yes"]] |
|      Joe  | Root   |Player     |["Age": "31", "Country": "ENG", "tags": ["Gen": "M", "Fit": "Yes"]] |
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the `Metadata` column, the outer `Map` is already a `typedLit`, adding another Map within it is not being allowed.

Comment: What's the question actually? What is your input schema/data and what do you want to do (expected output)? Please clarify your question

Comment: @blackbishop, I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Column `Metadata` is of type MapType or StructType? You can't have different values types for type map in Spark, but this possible for structs.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet

Comment: @blackbishop, thanks for the suggestion. I was able to implement it with a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it using a struct. This is how it looks:

```
df.withColumn("Metadata", struct(lit("Age").alias("Age"), lit("Country").alias("Country"), typedLit(tags).alias("tags")))
```

It won't be exactly key val pair but still be queryable with alias.